# Change border color of Entry on focus

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom Entry for my Xamarin.Forms Android app. Currently, I'm using a Custom Renderer to give the Entry an oval shape with a border.

I also want to change the color of the Entry Border on focus and revert back to the original color on unfocus.

My custom Renderer is below:

```
public class EntryCellRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var UIEntry = (e.NewElement != null) ? (EntryCell)e.NewElement : (EntryCell)e.OldElement;

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Control.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            Control.SetPadding(30, 30, 30, 31);
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);

            var BackgroundColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_DEFAULT_CLEAR);
            var ColorRef = Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(
                (byte)(BackgroundColor.A * 255),
                (byte)(BackgroundColor.R * 255),
                (byte)(BackgroundColor.G * 255),
                (byte)(BackgroundColor.B * 255));


            gd.SetColor((int)ColorRef);

            UIEntry.BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
            gd.SetStroke(7, Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);
            gd.SetCornerRadius(20.0f);
            Control.SetBackground(gd);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with having a focus event for what I want to do above with this custom Entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnElementChanged` you can wire up an event to the `Focused` event:

```
e.NewElement.Unfocused += (sender, evt) =>
{
    // unfocused, set color
};
e.NewElement.Focused += (sender, evt) =>
{
    // focus, set color
};
```

FYI: The `OnNativeFocusChanged` would be the perfect place to do this with an override, but it is not public...

```
internal virtual void OnNativeFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
{
}
```

Comment: Ok great, this works but when I try to unfocus out of my entry, it won't let me unfocus or change color back. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Euridice01 Not sure I understand. You are not getting a `Focused` event call for when the view focus changes to not focused? Or...? i.e. This line is not being called? https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4f8af14f13f34d9b66d92e315c8486edd28e851a/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/ViewRenderer.cs#L62

Comment: So, on page load... the entry is not focused. Then I tap it and it is focused. After I'm done typing inside the entry and tap outside the entry.... It does not become unfocused. This page inherits from ContentPage (Not sure if ViewRenderer is called?). How can I best debug this? Btw, I am using Xamarin.Forms 1.5.6... not sure if it is a bug or not.

Comment: I created a separate unFocus event and it works. Looks like adding it to the Focus event will not trigger unFocus.... I think maybe it's a bug with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @Euridice01 You are correct, I updated my answer. In Android, it is a single event via implementing a `IOnFocusChangeListener`, I forgot that `Forms` breaks that into two separate events, which is confusing (at least to me) since the event contains a `IsFocused` property....

Answer (score 0):

You could wire up an `Action` to be run when ever your `Focus` event gets called. So you would add a new `Action` property to your custom `EntryCell` and also wire up the `Focus`:

```
public class CustomEntryCell : EntryCell {

    public Action OnFocusEventAction { get; set; }

    public CustomEntryCell() { Focused += OnFocused }

    private void OnFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs focusEventArgs) { OnFocusEventAction?.Invoke(); }

    ///Or if you are not at C# 6 yet:
    //private void OnFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs focusEventArgs) {
    //    Action action = OnFocusEventAction;
    //    if(action != null) { action.Invoke(); }
    //}
}
```

Then you Custom Renderer would assign something to the control's `Action`:

```
public class EntryCellRenderer : EntryRenderer {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e) {
        ....
        UIEntry.OnFocusEventAction = () => //Your custom border color change code here
        ....
    }
}
```

Wrote this all out of memory and in this text box so if something does not work let me know and I will spend more time on it!

Comment: Seems to work but the entry does not become unfocused when I tap outside of the entry. The entry is on a contentpage.

Comment: I created a separate unFocus event and it works. Looks like adding it to the Focus event will not trigger unFocus.... I think maybe it's a bug with Xamarin.Forms?